# Apache Velocity Quiet Reference Notation as default behaviour

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

When Velocity encounters an undefined reference, its normal behavior is to output the image of the reference. For example, suppose the following reference appears as part of a VTL template" example:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="$!email"/>
```

Is it possible to configure a default behaviour, so that I could still write `$email` and it's implicitly a quiet notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  There's an event handler which is called when an invalid reference is found.  It's called InvalidReferenceEventHandler.   You'll want to have the event handler return an empty string.

```
public Object invalidGetMethod( Context context, 
                                    String reference, 
                                    Object object, 
                                    String property, 
                                    Info info)
{
    return "";
}
```

Consult the Velocity Developer's Guide for details on how to create and register an event handler.  But in a nutshell, implement InvalidReferenceEventHandler and then include this property when setting up your VelocityEngine.

```
eventhandler.invalidreferences.class=com.something.youreventhandlerclass
```

Comment: here a dynamic way
http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Event_Handlers